# SSH to host via SSH gateway with PuTTY

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, proxy, putty

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
Windows host -> Windows SSH Gateway -> End Host
```

So SSH into and an End Host via an SSH Gateway.

```
Session 1: SSH Tunnel -> SSH Gateway
Session 2: SSH -> End Host
```

I've created a session with the SSH tunnel to the gateway like this:
[Session 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1vrH.png)

The session is open and working fine; I can even see the port opened in netstat.

My problem is with the 2nd session, which would go to the host via the gateway. I cant figure out how to use the first session I've created for the SSH traffic. I've tried every Proxy type, but none worked:
[Session 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3USY.png)

I've checked and the end host is reachable from the Gateway.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

These are the steps I found on [this blog](https://www.webscalability.com/blog/2014/06/sshing-via-a-gateway-host-using-putty/):

> 1. Set up key authentication to your host with PuttyGen & Pageant (ssh-agent for Putty) – or KittyGen & Kageant if you’re using Kitty. Paste your public key into authorized_hosts on the gateway & destination box.
> 2. Set up your configuration, IP address in session should be of destination (see screenshot, this is an internal IP).
> 3. Go to Connection -> SSH -> Auth. Check **Allow agent forwarding**.
> 4. Connection -> Proxy. Enter your gateway IP in Proxy hostname & exclude Hosts, choose Proxy type **local** & put your username in the box.
>
> In telnet command put
>
> ```
> klink.exe %user@%proxyhost -nc %host:%port \n
> ```
>
> (or plink.exe if using putty). This will be run first to tunnel your connection through.
>
> [image]

5. Done!

Comment: The answer I posted above was from https://www.webscalability.com/blog/2014/06/sshing-via-a-gateway-host-using-putty/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I've tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then I don't know what you should do.